# reference request: question about representation of binary quadratic forms

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, quadratic-forms

Let $Q$ be an indefinite binary quadratic form with integer coefficients. Suppose it is primitive and  irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. I am looking for the following fact.
Let $n > 1$. Suppose $n = F(x_1, y_1)$ and $n = F(x_2, y_2)$ where $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are distinct integral pairs.

I am looking for a reference for the following fact (which I think is true):
Then there exists an integral automorph $T$ such that $(x_2, y_2) = T(x_1, y_1)$.

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you are doing:   what automorph  would you like for $x^2 - 5 y^2 = 209,$  one answer $(17,4)$  and another $(23,8) \; ? \; \; $

Comment: I guess I was thinking that all solutions were parametrized by automorphs...